# How to get child node data using simplexml

Tags: xml

---

### This is my xml file.

```
<Client>
  <Name>
    <First>John</First>
    <Last>Doe</Last>
  </Name>
  <Userid>2</Userid>
  <Email>enter code herejohn.doe@gmail.com</Email>
<Client
```

---

### This is code i am trying to get the data from child nodes of name tag.

```
$xml = simple_xml_load('client.xml');
$xml->getChildren()
but i am not able to get the data from the required node.the output is nothing.
```

Comment: Consider editing your question to describe the problem that you want to resolve.

Comment: i've edited the question.Can you please help now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the child to child nodes can be using xpath.
$xml->xpath("Client/Name/First").

If the text content is required then use strip_tag method in php.